# MVC asp.net Ajax form action return Json result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I have a problem with an Ajax form in MVC asp.net. When I post the form and try to return a json result from action, my `Onsuccess` method doesn't fire and the view is not displayed. There are only json objects that are displayed as if `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not working.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert("oki");
            if (response.success == true) {
               
                $(location).attr('href', response.ReturnUrl);
            }
            else {
                $('form').clearForm();
                $("#message").css("display", "block");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("login2",new {ReturnUrl=Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]}, new AjaxOptions
        {
            OnSuccess = "OnSuccess"
            
        }))
        {
           
            @Html.Label("Nom :", new { @class = "monlabel" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new { placeHolder = "Nom", @class = "tb" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login)
           
            @Html.Label("Mot de passe :", new { @class = "monlabel" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { placeHolder = "Mot de passe", @class = "tb" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            <input id="bouton" type="submit" value="Valider" /><br />
               
        
            
        }
    <div><p style="display:none" id="message">Authentification erronée</p></div>


</body>
</html>
```

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult login2(Models.Utilisateur utilisateur, string ReturnUrl)
    {


        Models.LoginDataContext MyDb = new Models.LoginDataContext();

        Models.Utilisateur tmpUser = null;
        ViewBag.result = "oki";
        tmpUser = MyDb.ValidateUser(utilisateur.Login, utilisateur.Password).FirstOrDefault();
        if (tmpUser != null)
        {
            Session["User"] = tmpUser;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tmpUser.Login, false);
            //return RedirectToAction("AccesValider");
            if (ReturnUrl != null) return Json(new {success=true,@ReturnUrl=ReturnUrl},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else return Json(new {success=true,@ReturnUrl=FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(new {success=false,@ReturnUrl =""},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

I get this result:

```
{"success":true,"ReturnUrl":"/Home/Index"}
```

in the browser

Comment: Your `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not loading. see browser console.log for any errors. and the file path of this file. If any errors please mention thank you.

Comment: Or maybe `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is not set to `true` in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

To use any `@Ajax` functionality in ASP.NET MVC you need a valid reference to the jquery.unobtrusive library.If you are getting `{"success":true,"ReturnUrl":"/Home/Index"}` as the response it's a dead give away that you're not referencing the jquery.unobtrusive library correctly.

**You have two options:**

1.Replace this line in your code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ajax.unobtrusive/3.2.4/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

2.If you don't want to use the CDN you can install the jquery.unobtrusive nuget package.

2.1 In Visual Studio click TOOLS -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

2.2 Type `Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` and press Enter.

2.3 Drag and drop `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file from Visual Studio Solution Explorer into your web page to create the reference